# if-statement with two conditions is ignored

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

It´s probably a too easy question for a forum, but I´m kinda hard stuck and my prog skills are very limited. After submitting a userform in vba, I want the program to check if the user made a logic mistake. There are several CheckBoxes and a combination of selections is possible, but not all combinations are allowed. So I have written the following code to prevent the user from submitting the form with selecting two specific CheckBoxes.
But the program completely ignores this if-statement and no matter what CheckBoxes are selected, nothing changes.

```
If userform1.CheckBoxOption3.Value = True And userform1.CheckBoxOption7.Value = True Then
MsgBox "This Combination is not possible!", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Edit: Additional Code:

```
Private Sub CmdFertig_Click()

Worksheets("sheets1").Range("I22").Value = userform1.TextBox1.Value & "°"
Worksheets("sheets1").Range("I13").Value = userform1.TextBox2.Value & "°"
Worksheets("sheets1").Range("E17").Value = userform1.TextBox3.Value & "°"

If userform1.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    Worksheets("sheets1").Range("g24").Value = userform1.TextBox1.Value & "°"
End If

If userform1.CheckBox2.Value = False Then
    Worksheets("sheets1").Range("f24").Value = ""
    Worksheets("sheets1").Range("f25").Value = ""
End If

If userform1.CheckBox3.Value = True Then
    Worksheets("sheets1").Range("g25").Value = "Wechselseitig"
End If

If userform1.CheckBox5.Value = True Then
    Worksheets("sheets1").Range("g25").Value = "Einseitig"
End If

If userform1.CheckBox7.Value = True Then
    Worksheets("sheets1").Range("h25").Value = "Im UZ voreilend"
End If

If userform1.CheckBox3.Value = True And userform1.CheckBox7.Value = True Then
    MsgBox "This Combination is not possible!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

userform1.Hide

Worksheets("sheets1").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    Filename:=userform1.Text1.Value & ".pdf", _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
    
Dim sPath As String

    sPath = "O:\F1\completed\"

    With Worksheets("sheets1")
        .ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=sPath & userform1.TextBox1.Value & ".pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End With
SetAttr sPath & userform1.TextBox1.Value & ".pdf", vbReadOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: is it still userform1 ?

Comment: yes, the entire program is based only on userform1

Comment: Then perhaps you should show the complete code. Or what values are actually in the checkboxes...

Comment: By default the CheckBox values are "false" so they are un-checked when starting the form.

Comment: How the above code is called? 1. Are you sure that the code is somehow called? Inside an event code? I mean, are you sure that it runs when you think it should? 2. Please, place a breakpoint on the first code line you show and run the code. If **it stops on the breakpoint**, move the cursor over the two involved chec boxes. What does it show for each of them? If not, check the way of calling, running the calling code line by line (pressing `F8`) and see what it does/does not...

Comment: Let me guess: You are using the infamous `unload me`-statement to close the form?

Comment: @FunThomas nope

Comment: But the user closes the userform by clicking the `x` on the top right, doesn't he?

Comment: @Storax no, the form is closed by the click of a button which, besides closing the form, puts values into excel cells depending on the checked boxes and filled textboxes

Comment: We need to see more of the code (the full sub, ideally). There must be a reason your code isn't running, as the test itself seems correct.

Comment: Ok, how do you instantiate the userform? It seems you do use the [default instance](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) what is normally a bad idea. You need to show more of your code.

Comment: @SolarMike I have posted the code. I still tried to answer the other questions. no need to be unfriendly

Comment: How do you call the userform?

Comment: Was being factual, good that you have added the code. Have you tried adding the breakpoints as suggested?

Comment: @Storax userform1. or do you mean something else?

Comment: If you use `userform1` in the code of the userform1 itself it will call the default instance.

Comment: Userform1 is a userform. So, you could do sth like that `Dim f as new Userform1` and then `f.show`. So, how do you call your userform? I strongly recommend not to use the default instance and especially do not refer to the default instance in userform code itself.

Comment: I have changed the term userform1 to an other name but nothing changed.

Comment: @SolarMike didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step like suggestd in my comments I would remove the references to the default instance in the code itself. Like written [here](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)

> A UserForm is essentially a class module with a designer and a
> VB_PredeclaredId attribute. That PredeclaredId means VBA is
> automatically creating a global-scope instance of the class, named
> after that class.

> UserForm1.Show at the call site, where UserForm1 isn’t a local
> variable but the “hey look it’s free” default instance, which means
> you’re using an object without even realizing it (at least without
> New​-ing it up yourself) – and you’re storing state that belongs to a
> global instance, which means you’re using an object but without the
> benefits of object-oriented programming.

So removing all references to the default instance in the code might already help. For the posted code

```
Private Sub CmdFertig_Click()

    Worksheets("sheets1").Range("I22").Value = TextBox1.Value & "°"
    Worksheets("sheets1").Range("I13").Value = TextBox2.Value & "°"
    Worksheets("sheets1").Range("E17").Value = TextBox3.Value & "°"

    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        Worksheets("sheets1").Range("g24").Value = TextBox1.Value & "°"
    End If

    If CheckBox2.Value = False Then
        Worksheets("sheets1").Range("f24").Value = ""
        Worksheets("sheets1").Range("f25").Value = ""
    End If

    If CheckBox3.Value = True Then
        Worksheets("sheets1").Range("g25").Value = "Wechselseitig"
    End If

    If CheckBox5.Value = True Then
        Worksheets("sheets1").Range("g25").Value = "Einseitig"
    End If

    If CheckBox7.Value = True Then
        Worksheets("sheets1").Range("h25").Value = "Im UZ voreilend"
    End If

    If CheckBox3.Value = True And CheckBox7.Value = True Then
        MsgBox "This Combination is not possible!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Hide

    Worksheets("sheets1").ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        Filename:=Text1.Value & ".pdf", _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
    
    Dim sPath As String

    sPath = "O:\F1\completed\"

    With Worksheets("sheets1")
        .ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=sPath & TextBox1.Value & ".pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End With
    SetAttr sPath & TextBox1.Value & ".pdf", vbReadOnly

End Sub
```

I also suggest to read about

[VBA Userform](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-userform/)

[Addvanded Tips on Userform](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/userforms_advanced_tips.html)

Comment: This solved the problem, now the if-statement works. THANK YOU